# Change/Add Name of Managed Instance after Activation in Systems Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-systems-manager

I have been setting up Amazon EC2 Systems Manager in order to manage our Windows patch management setup.  All looking good so far as we can get the on premises servers listed in the console using the activation.

I have activated the following servers on the same activation (without entering a name as part of the activation).  As I have now around 5 managed instances on there they have no name.  In the MI section I can see the computer name but when it comes to the run command or to do anything I am only able to see the instance ID.

[AWS ECS Systems Manager - Managed Instances, need to be able to set the name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMvB3.jpg)

How can I go back and update the name for these managed instances?  Don't really have to add each server on a seperate individual activation again?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the name of your managed instances by setting the Name tag on the instance. At the moment you have to use the AWS CLI or the AWS PowerShell tools to do this, but once done you'll see the name in the console.

You can find the AWS CLI documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/add-tags-to-resource.html

```
> aws ssm add-tags-to-resource --resource-type ManagedInstance --resource-id <your managed instance id> --tags Key=Name,Value=<instance name<
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That works great, just sorted my managed instances.  How can I do it for instances (EC2).  Doesn't seem to be a resource type of instance?

Comment: Sorted it now.  Added tag as normal to the EC2 instance in the web console.  Showing as the name correctly now.